# TypeScript - instanceof does not work for JSON

Tags: json, typescript, ionic3

I am using IONIC v3.0.1 and trying to determine the error type received from the server. The sample error responses are

```
// HTTP Errors
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"long error description"}

// Java Exception
{"timestamp":00000000000,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.Exception","message":"Java Exception","path":"/app/login"}
```

I have created respective classes to represent these different errors

```
// for HTTP Error
export class HTTPError {
  constructor() {

  }

  public error: string;
  public error_description: string;
}


// for Java Error
export class JavaError {
  constructor() {

  }

  public error: string;
  public exception: string;
  public message: string;
  public path: string;
  public status: number;
  public timestamp: Date;
}
```

I am trying to determine the type of error by using instanceof keyword

```
...
let error: any = JSON.parse(response);
if (error instanceof HTTPError) {
  // Condition Block 1
} else if (error instanceof JavaError) {
  // Condition Block 2
} else {
  // Condition Block 3
}
...
```

For any response, the execution goes into Condition Block 3.
The if conditions always evaluate to false.

What am I doing wrong here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` returns an Object with no prototype, so there is no way instanceof will ever work. If your json contains "type" information then you can use that to compare or you have to compare if certain properties exist to identify correct object.

The only alternative is to check if it has any property that belongs to class..

```
if(error.error){
   if(error.error_description){
       // this is HttpError
   }
   else if(error.exception){
       // this is JavaError
   }
}else{
     // success...
}
```

Comment: That is a good point you pointed out that there is no prototype for the Object. I will wait to see if they are any other workarounds and if not will take your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You'll never reach "condition 1" or "condition 2" because '[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)' operator tests prototype chains:

> The instanceof operator tests whether the prototype property of a
>   constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

The return value of [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is:

> The [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) corresponding to the given JSON text.

`JSON.parse()` can not determine types, it just returns an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) instance NOT `HTTPError` or `JavaError` instance, you should test special properties instead of using `instanceof` operator:

```
...
let resp: any = JSON.parse(response);
if (resp.error) {
   if (resp.error_description) {
      // handle HTTPError
   } else if (resp.exception) {
      // handle JavaError
   }
}
...
```