# Can't load TypeScript objects from MongoDB serverless

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb

I am converting my reactjs project to typescript. But I can't get any of my typescript classes to instantiate properly from server responses. I'm using a MongoDB Atlas serverless back end, so this is client code:

```
async getAll(page = 0): Promise<MidiChart[]> {
    const midiChartsResponse: AxiosResponse<MidiChart[]> = await http.get(`midicharts?page=${page}}`);
    console.log(`midiCharts: ${JSON.stringify(midiChartsResponse.data)}`)
    const midiCharts: MidiChart[] = midiChartsResponse.data;
    console.log(`midiChart ${midiCharts[0] instanceof MidiChart} ${JSON.stringify(midiCharts[0])}`)
```

Response line output:

```
0, {"_id":"630394a33871337817fd9f57","inputNames":["minilogue xd KBD/KNOB"],"outputNames":["minilogue xd SOUND"],"midiCcs":{"cutoff":{"name":"cutoff","ccMsb":43,"ccLsb":63,"max":1023,"min":0},"resonance":{"name":"resonance","ccMsb":44,"ccLsb":64,"max":127,"min":0}}} instanceof MidiChart? false
```

The object looks correct, but 'instanceof' returns false.

```
    midiChart false {"_id":"630394a33871337817fd9f57","inputNames":["minilogue xd KBD/KNOB"],"outputNames":["minilogue xd SOUND"],"midiCcs":{"cutoff":{"name":"cutoff","ccMsb":43,"ccLsb":63,"max":1023,"min":0},"resonance":{"name":"resonance","ccMsb":44,"ccLsb":64,"max":127,"min":0}}}
```

I have no idea how to fix this and can't find a good example of how to this from a React client with a MongoDB Atlas back end.

Comment: Checkout answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599275/typescript-instanceof-does-not-work-for-json). In short, JS objects from a JSON response may be structurally compatible with your TS types, but they are not instances of these objects in the strict sense, i.e. prototype chain. If your `MidiChart` class contains methods, then you may want to add a constructor that populates the fields of the class from the JSON. If not, you may convert `MidiChart` to an interface and structural compatibility is enough.

Comment: Thanks @NikosParaskevopoulos that was helpful. I have created constructors that take an any as a parameter. I think it's a joke that typescript lets me construct broken objects though.

Comment: Just to console you about the objects: imagine the following case in Java: `class Foo { int x; int y; }`, `class Bar { int x; int y; }`. These are *structurally* the same, but you can never assign an instance of Foo to an instance of Bar because they are strictly different classes. TS on the other hand understands the fact that these classes are structurally similar and, by design, allows you to assign between them. This decision helps in some cases, but provides unexpected results in others, like: `const a: Foo = new Foo(); const b: Bar = a; b instanceof Bar // false`. Happy coding anyway!

Comment: That is insane!